# How to learn to move objects by means of a script in python?

Tags: python

I'm learning how to handle the blender program. I do not know anything at all. I would like to know how to draw the panel and most importantly, how to control objects using a python script, and the video game engine blender game logic; Where can I get the information?

i like to do this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVtZPQGt5PM

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know anything at all as you say, i suggest you that search tutorials on YouTube (there's a lot) and you can found information about Blender game Engine in the Python API documentation [Python API bge.KX_GameObject](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=object) where you would see the functions that handles and object like:

move object:

```
from bge import logic
logic.getCurrentController().owner.localLinearVelocity.y = 0.5
## also localLinearVelocity = (0,0.5,0) or setLinearVelocity(vector, local=True)
```

rotate object:

```
from bge import logic
logic.getCurrentController().owner.applyRotation((0,0,0.02))
```

where owner is the object who has the Python controller (currentController) linked in it logic editor like this image:

[image]